# Cordova iOS - transition causes page flash

Tags: ios, cordova, css-transitions

I am developing an application in Cordova, where the user can switch between a few 'screens', which are just hidden divs brought into view by a transition.

The scrolling on iOS has been terrible, so I added `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch` to the container element and it sorted out the scrolling issue I had.

However, since then the page transitions cause the pages to flash each time the application moves to a new page.

Here is my CSS

```
.scrollable {
    overflow: scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

Once a button is pressed to proceed to the next page it uses this javascript code for the transition

```
this.lastScreen.getLayout().getElement().css({
    'left': -$(window).width(),
    'transition': 'left 0.25s ease-out'
});

this.currentScreen.getLayout().getElement().css({
    'left': 0,
    'transition': 'left 0.25s ease-out'
});

<div class="container scrollable">
    //screen content here
</div>
```

If I remove the `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` from the scrollable class it works fine, no flash happens. However, the scrolling of the page is terrible.

I am running iOS 9.3.1. I read around and found out this may have been an issue from iOS 8+ but can't really find a difinitve answer to help me

Comment: Have you tried separating the scroll from the transition? DIV1 is the transition and inside it, DIV2 has the scroll attribute.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to use native transitions with cordova´s app.

http://plugins.telerik.com/cordova/plugin/native-page-transitions

Answer (score 3):

Add this CSS to the classes that have transitions:

```
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0px,0px,0px);
```

It just force hardware acceleration, so it become smoother than the normal one, and probably fix your issues

Comment: Would I add this to the CSS of this.lastScreen.getLayout().getElement()?

Comment: Yes, in every place that a transition is not smooth

Comment: Okay i'll give it a try

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunately, still get the flash when the screen moves and the next screen shows :(